# setup windows xp Network credential

Tags: networking, windows-xp, windows-8.1

I have two machines , Windows XP Machine and Windows 8.1 Machine , in public network that connected to other Machines

I want to share my folders and files over the public network , i want to share it securely

My question is how to set username and password for windows xp machine network so i can access shared folders by windows 8.1 machine ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily share Windows shared drives over a public network. Windows does not encrypt the traffic between the machines (except for the login).

To do so securely, you need to set up a "Virtual Private Network" (VPN). This provides a "tunnel" which is an encrypted link between the 2 networks. You could research IPSEC based VPN's.

Tools such as [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) can be used to set up VPN's or tools such as [TeamDrive](http://www.teamdrive.com/) or even DropBox are alternatives that can reasonably securely share files.